# Can SNS pass user-metadata to rest layer after object created event?

Tags: rest, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

I need to pass user-metadata when I perform a put action to add new objects to an s3 bucket.  After the file is uploaded (object is created), I would like the s3:ObjectCreated:put to pass a notification to a rest api method call for further processing.

I have found doc on how to pass user-metadata to the put operation, but not doc on how to make the sns message contain the user-metadata when sending the message to the rest api method.

Would the sns message automatically contain the user-metadata for the newly created object or would I have to perform some additional configuration to make this happen?

Update:

Should I generate a head request like this using node.js:

```
       let authString: string = "AWS AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:02236Q3V0RonhpaBX5sCYVf1bNRuU=";
        var options = {
            host: 'bucket.s3.amazonaws.com',
            path: '/filename.jpg',
            method: 'HEAD',
            headers: { 'Authorization': authString, 'Date': 'Date: Wed, 28 Oct 2009 22:32:00 GMT' }
        };

        var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
            res.on('data', function(d) {
                process.stdout.write(d);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code that receives the SNS message will need to send a `HEAD` request to the bucket to fetch the object's metadata.  This operation goes under various names similar to `getObjectMetadata` in the SDKs.

It isn't included in the event notification.

Or you could code a Lambda function to receive the initial event, fetch the metadata, and combine everything into a new notification message structure containing everything you need, and send it back over to SNS or SQS or directly to your API.

Comment: So you are saying that after sns invokes the rest call and passed data to the rest method, it then becomes the responsibility of the rest layer to make a separate call inside the rest method to perform the head request?  Similar to this doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html#RESTObjectHEAD-responses-examples

Comment: Correct.  The metadata is not included in the event notification, it has to be fetched.

Comment: This might be a stupid and if so, I apologize, this will be a first attempt at this.  Would the request in node, look something like this what I added above?

Comment: a head request that is.

Comment: See [`headObject()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property) in the Node SDK.  There are a lot of parameters shown in the example, but most are optional.